# String slicing in specific scenarios Python

Tags: python, string, slice

I have a string I'd like to split to new strings which will contain only text (no commas, spaces, dots etc.). The length of each new string must be of variable n. The slicing must go through each possible combination.
Meaning, for example, an input of `func('banana pack', 3)` will result in ['ban','ana','nan','ana',pac','ack']. So far what I managed to achieve is:

```
def func(text, n):
    text = text.lower()
    text = text.translate(str.maketrans("", "", " .,"))
    remainder = len(text) % n
    split_text = [text[i:i + n] for i in range(0, len(text) - remainder, n)]
    if remainder > 0:
        split_text.append(text[-n:])
    return split_text
```

Comment: In your example `'ana'` is two times inside the result. Do you want this?

Comment: You have already coded, may I know what is the ask here ?

Comment: @Dischoni -- I don't see it twice -- ['ban', 'ana', 'pac', 'ack'] 4
{'ban': 0.3, 'ana': 0.3, 'pac': 0.3, 'ack': 0.3}

Comment: @Dschoni yes it is wanted

Comment: Can your input have commas, spaces and dots?

Comment: @Dschoni yes, func('banana.,  pack', 3) will result the same as the example in the original question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I clean the input, by removing `','` and `'.'`. The input is then split at spaces to take only full words into account. For each word the sections are appended.

```
def func(text,n):
    text=text.replace('.','').replace(',','') #Cleanup
    words = text.split() #split words
    output = []
    for word in words:
        for i in range(len(word)-n+1):
            output.append(word[i:i+n])
    return output
```

You could unroll the loop one level if you just iterate over everything and discard results with unwanted symbols.